# Formating XML import file to database with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to transform a import file before I read it into my database.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import>
    <Lines>
        <Line>
            <TransactionId>1</TransactionId>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            <ItemCategoryId>1</ItemCategoryId>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <TransactionId>1</TransactionId>
            <Sequence>0</Sequence>
            <ItemId>0</ItemId>
        </Line>
    </Lines>
</Import>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- matches on each author -->
    <xsl:template match="Line">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />                
            <OrderId>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Sequence > 0 or ItemId > 0 ">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </OrderId>                
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import>
    <Lines>
        <Line>
            <TransactionId>1</TransactionId>
            <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            <ItemCategoryId>1</ItemCategoryId>
            <OrderId>1</OrderId>
        </Line>
        <Line>
            <TransactionId>1</TransactionId>
            <Sequence>0</Sequence>
            <ItemId>0</ItemId>
            <OrderId>0</OrderId>
        </Line>
    </Lines>
</Import>
```

This works fine to insert each Line with with the correct `OrderId` value, but what I really want to do is the following:

If one of the Line `OrderId` value is set to 1, I want all `OrderId`'s in every line to be set to 1.

I need to do this since `OrderId` is actually stored on a order level in my database, but imported on line level. Since I will get different values in sequence and `ItemId`, I will at some point set it to 0 when I actually want it to be 1.

Usually I would just get the third party to send me correct and same `OrderId` in the xml, but because of several reason they cant do this.

Do anyone know how I can achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your condition. There are two `Line`s in the input and none of them has an `OrderId` property. Please restate the required logic more clearly.

Comment: i edited my post. I hope you understand now. The answer below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a 'global' variable and the `//` expression which

> Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are

So create a variable at stylesheet level

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="orderby" select="//Line/Sequence > 0 or //Line/ItemId > 0" /> 
  ...
```

and use it in your `OrderId` code

```
<OrderId>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$orderby">
            <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</OrderId>
```